# Changing font color for entire application or activity via code(java)

Tags: java, android, fonts

Is it possible to change font color for entire application or activity via code(java)? I want to read color from shared preferences and then change the font color inside the activity. I have done that for background and it works, but I do not know how to change font globaly.

```
    public void usePreferences(){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(OptionListActivity.MY_PREFERENCES, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        String backColorAsString = settings.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.background_color), "0");
        Log.i(getResources().getString(R.string.font_color), backColorAsString);
        int backColorRGB = 0;
        if (backColorAsString.equals("RED"))
            backColorRGB = Color.RED;
        else if (backColorAsString.equals("BLUE"))
            backColorRGB = Color.BLUE;
        else if (backColorAsString.equals("GREEN"))
            backColorRGB = Color.GREEN;

        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(backColorRGB);

//works great till here


String fontColorAsString = settings.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.font_color), "0");
        int fColorRGB = 0;
        if (fontColorAsString.equals("RED"))
            fColorRGB = Color.RED;
        else if (fontColorAsString.equals("BLUE"))
            fColorRGB = Color.BLUE;
        else if (fontColorAsString.equals("GREEN"))
            fColorRGB = Color.GREEN;

//WHAT TO DO NOW?   
    }
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    usePreferences();
}
```

Comment: look this http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PART 1**

You could create a custom TextView. For the text color to be set the fastest, set the global color in your application class. (Not main activity)

```
public class ColorTextView extends TextView {

    private static int color = Color.BLUE;

    public ColorTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public ColorTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public ColorTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public static void setGlobalColor(int newcolor) {
        color = newcolor;
    }
}
```

And use it in the xml like:

```
<your.package.name.ColorTextView
     //other stuff
/>
```

And finally you can set color in your code like:

```
ColorTextView.setGlobalColor(yourColor);
```

**PART 2**

Setup an application class like the following and paste the `usepreferences()` code into it.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // paste code and set color here
    }
}
```

Finally, for this to run, you'll have to declare it in your Manifest in the application tag:

```
android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
```

Comment: This is for TextView. I meant change font color for entire application. Buttons, labels, everything. Further more if I create my own class I can;t use it right in the xml...

Comment: Im sorry, uh you could create a custom version for buttons as well and declare them in the XML. As most of the time, you'll be using text views, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Yes and that helped! The only problem left is that I do not know the font color before I read shared preferences thus I can't set it for buttons. I need read it first, but at the time buttons already exist.

Comment: As I said in my answer. Setup an Application class, where you'll check sharedpreferences for a color but if it's null or something, you'll have a default color ready to set.

Comment: I did and I did that, but it caused new problem. In Main activity I had finish() on back button and now it stopped worked.

Comment: I did not know why finish() stopped work but adding permissions in manifest and changing finish to System.exit(0) helped. Thank you for your time. Sorry for my spelling it is 8 am here... no sleep at all.

Comment: Did you try adding context? this.finish(). And it's 10 here. Even so, glad it worked out.